# Transform a string according to a table of replacements

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I need to create a QR code out of a few pieces of user-entered information, we will call them a b and c. I am doing this using a google sheet document and embedding this formula into a cell:

```
=if(isblank(A4), "", image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&A4&B4&C4))
```

Which uses this API:

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

I need to concatenate these pieces of information, but I also need to do some trickery on b.

Specifically, b is a fixed string of 8 characters (ex. K1J05359). As it turns out, the 3rd character (always a letter), corresponds to a two-digit number that I need. Here is how these letters are mapped, and these are the only letters that will be used:

```
00-B
01-C
02-D
03-E
04-F
05-G
06-H
07-J
08-K
09-L
10-M
11-N
12-P
13-Q
14-R
15-S
16-T
17-U
```

I need to extract the 3rd character (in this case, J), and change b so that it goes from K1J05359 to 07K105359. And that's where I am stuck.

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for phrasing this problem?

Comment: The current title `Transform a string according to a table of replacements` looks much better than the original.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a lookup table for the letter->digits substitutions.

```
+----+-----+
|  A |  00 |
|  B |  01 |
|  C |  02 |
+----+-----+
```

(To enter strings like "00", use `="00"`). Suppose this table is in cells E1:F18. Then given a string like K1J05359 in cell G1, you can convert it with

```
=vlookup(mid(G1, 3, 1), E1:F18, 2, 0) & left(G1, 2) & right(G1, 5)
```

The formula is more or less self-descriptive: look up the 3rd character in the table, then put the first two characters, then the last five.